# Vibrate not working on Android 4.3 Jelly Bean Update

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, vibration

Samsung Galaxy S3.

I go to Settings > My device > Sound > Vibrations

Before the Jelly Bean update, I had a custom vibration which was a medium length vibration. Now, after the Jelly Bean update a little while ago, it's just two short vibrations.

I've changed my vibration after I noticed this to "Jingle Bell" and it's still the same vibration. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem. it's my understanding that as of now that is the default text message vibration and can not be changed

Comment: I hope that's not true :(

Comment: I've been searching forums all nights that's what they all say I've also been trying to get rid of my messages being displayed on the lock screen but u can't do that either

Comment: It must be a glitch, but one that can't be fixed right now. It's pathetic.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings → My device → Sounds → Vibrate intensity → Haptic feedback → turn up to fall. This will fix your problem .I had mine turned to low, hence no vibrate fixed when turned it up.

Comment: This needs further edit since  "*turn up to fall*" and "*no vibrate fixed when turned it up*" isn't making sense, at least to me.